# How to get the actual value of a cell with openpyxl?

Tags: csv, openpyxl

I'm a beginner with Python and I need help. I'm using Python 2.7 and I'm trying to retrieve the cell values of an excel file and store it into a csv file. My code is the following:

```
import os, openpyxl, csv
aggname = "deu"

wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only = True)
app_file = open(filename,'a')
dest_file = csv.writer(app_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

calib_sheet = wb_source.get_sheet_by_name('Calibration')
data = calib_sheet['B78:C88']
data = list(data)
print(data)

for i in range(len(data)):
    dest_file.writerow(data[i])

app_file.close()
```

In my csv file, I get this, instead of the actual value (for example in my case: SFCG, 99103).

```
<Cell Calibration.B78>,<Cell Calibration.C78>
<Cell Calibration.B79>,<Cell Calibration.C79>
<Cell Calibration.B80>,<Cell Calibration.C80>
<Cell Calibration.B81>,<Cell Calibration.C81>
<Cell Calibration.B82>,<Cell Calibration.C82>
<Cell Calibration.B83>,<Cell Calibration.C83>
<Cell Calibration.B84>,<Cell Calibration.C84>
<Cell Calibration.B85>,<Cell Calibration.C85>
<Cell Calibration.B86>,<Cell Calibration.C86>
<Cell Calibration.B87>,<Cell Calibration.C87>
<Cell Calibration.B88>,<Cell Calibration.C88>
```

I tried to set the data_only = True,  when opening the excel file as suggested in answers to similar questions but it doesn't solve my problem.

---------------EDIT-------------

Taking into account the first two answers I got (thank you!), I tried several things:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
   dest_file.writerows(data[i].value)
```

I get this error message :

```
for i in range(len(data)):
   dest_file.writerows(data[i].values)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-78-27828c989b39>", line 2, in <module>
    dest_file.writerows(data[i].values)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Then I tried this instead:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(2):
        dest_file.writerow(data[i][j].value)
```

and then I have the following error message:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(2):
        dest_file.writerow(data[i][j].value)


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-80-c571abd7c3ec>", line 3, in <module>
    dest_file.writerow(data[i][j].value)

Error: sequence expected
```

So then, I tried this:

```
import os, openpyxl, csv

wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
app_file = open(filename,'a')
dest_file = csv.writer(app_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')


calib_sheet = wb_source.get_sheet_by_name('Calibration')

list(calib_sheet.iter_rows('B78:C88'))

for row in calib_sheet.iter_rows('B78:C88'):
    for cell in row:
        dest_file.writerow(cell.value)
```

Only to get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-5bed62b45985>", line 12, in <module>
    dest_file.writerow(cell.value)

Error: sequence expected
```

For the "sequence expected" error I suppose python expects a list rather than a single cell, so I did this:

import os, openpyxl, csv

```
wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
app_file = open(filename,'a')
dest_file = csv.writer(app_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')


calib_sheet = wb_source.get_sheet_by_name('Calibration')

list(calib_sheet.iter_rows('B78:C88'))

for row in calib_sheet.iter_rows('B78:C88'):
        dest_file.writerow(row)
```

There is no error message but I only get the reference of the cell in csv file and changing it to dest_file.writerow(row.value) brings me back to the tuple error.

I obviously still need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it using numpy, which allows me to store my values as a list of lists rather than a list of tuples.

```
import os, openpyxl, csv
import numpy as np

wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
app_file = open(filename,'a')
dest_file = csv.writer(app_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')


calib_sheet = wb_source.get_sheet_by_name('Calibration')

store = list(calib_sheet.iter_rows('B78:C88'))
print store

truc = np.array(store)
print truc

for i in range(11):
    for j in range(1):
        dest_file.writerow([truc[i][j].value, truc[i][j+1].value]) 

app_file.close()
```

I actually have a sequence as my argument in "writerow()" and with the list object I can also use the double index and the value method to retrieve the value of my cell.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to get the cell's value! See [the documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook)

Answer (score -1):

Try using ***data.values*** instead of just ***data*** when you are printing it.

Hope it helps !!

**

```
***An example : 
import openpyxl 
import re 
import os 

wc=openpyxl.load_workbook('<path of the file>') wcsheet=wc.get_sheet_by_name('test')  
store=[] 

for data in wcsheet.columns[0]: 
    store=data 
print(store.value)***
=======================
```

=================================================

**

*Live Life Buddha Size*

Comment: Thank you but I get the following error when I apply your suggestion:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  `File "<ipython-input-77-2d959f2db22c>", line 2, in <module>
    dest_file.writerows(data[i].value)`

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Hey dessa .... Sorry that it didn't work out for you but happy that you got it done.. Learned something from you